# Upload Image to server in android by Httppost

Tags: android, http-post

How to upload image at server by gallary or camera?

I try [this link](http://curious-blog.blogspot.in/2013/06/pick-image-and-upload-to-server-in.html)'s code but it shows error like this

> Error:(329, 24) error: cannot access AbstractBody
>   class file for org.apache.james.mime4j.message.AbstractBody not found

Comment: Share your code.What you have try up to now?

Comment: (http://curious-blog.blogspot.in/2013/06/pick-image-and-upload-to-server-in.html) check this link i try this methods. bt it shows error @GeorgeThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload image to the server using http post multi-part. Here is the link which will help you out.

https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

And one more way to uploading image is, convert it into Base64 and than upload. Check the below link.

[Android upload image to server using base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987343/android-upload-image-to-server-using-base64)

Comment: thanks for this but its still showing this error @Vid

Comment: Error:(591, 22) error: cannot access AbstractBody
class file for org.apache.james.mime4j.message.AbstractBody not found
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.              this error i face mostly @Vid

Answer (score 0):

IF you use async-http as your http client [click-here](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) then you can use the following method[if you choose async-http you can use this method]
This method not only upload a image but can be also used to make normal post calls to the server.

YourFragment.class[this class were you call the http request]

```
 public class YourFragment extends CommanAbstract 
    {


    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
            ButterKnife.inject(this, v);

            return v;
        }


    private void linkCall() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("params1", "value1");
            params.put("params2", "value2");
//note that "image" tag will be the tag which accepts the file to the server
            params.put("image", new File("your image path from gallery or camera"));
            parse(params, 1, your link here, true);

        }
    @Override
        public void parseresult(String response, boolean success, int value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (value) {
            case 1:
                //here you can parse the link response
                break;
            }
        }

    @Override
        public void error(String response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //error will come here
        }

    }
```

CommanAbstract class[extends this class in which ever class you have an http request]

```
public abstract class CommanAbstract extends Fragment{

private static final String Url = "your link head here";

    public abstract void parseresult(String response, boolean success, int value);

    public abstract void error(String response);

    public void parse(RequestParams params, final int value, String link,
            boolean progrss) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method 

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        GlobalFunctions.postApiCall(getActivity(), link, params, client,
                new HttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(String response, boolean success) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (success) {
                            parseresult(response, true, value);
                        } else {
                            error(response);
                            toast("Connection error");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

GlobalFunctions class[this class calls the http request]

```
public class GlobalFunctions {
    // static ProgressDialog progress;

    public interface HttpResponseHandler {
        void handle(String response,boolean failre);
    }


    public static void postApiCall(final Context context, final String url,
            RequestParams params, AsyncHttpClient httpClient,
            final HttpResponseHandler handler) {

        httpClient.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String failureResponse) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                super.onFailure(arg0, failureResponse);
                System.out.println("fail" + failureResponse + "url is" + url);
                handler.handle(failureResponse,false);

                // errorToast(context);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {



                handler.handle(response,true);

            }
        });
    }

}
```